# Applying Cox modification to Conf. Interv. to $E(y)$ when we only observe $\log(y)$

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I'm trying to apply the Cox method [described in this article](http://jse.amstat.org/v13n1/olsson.html):

Using the notation in it, let $X\sim \log N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, i.e. $Y=\log(X) \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Hence, $E(X)=E(e^Y)=e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}$. An estimator for $\log(E(X))$ is $$\bar Y+\frac{S_Y^2}{2}$$. Also, $Var(\hat\log(E(X)))=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\frac{\sigma^4}{2(n-1)}$, which gives $$\hat Var(\hat\log(E(X)))=\frac{S_Y^2}{n}+\frac{S_Y^4}{2(n-1)}$$.

For large samples, using the CLT, we have $$\frac{\hat \log E(X)-\log E(X)}{\sqrt{\hat Var(\hat\log(E(X)))}}\sim^a N(0,1)$$

Thus, one possible CI from this perspective is $$CI(E(X))=\left]e^{\bar Y+\frac{S_Y^2}{2}\pm z_{1-\alpha}\sqrt{\frac{S_Y^2}{n}+\frac{S_Y^4}{2(n-1)}}}\right[$$.
According to the link, this is the Cox method, while the modified Cox method substitutes the standard normal quantile for a $t(n)$ quantile. They simulate more than just the these two intervals. They also simulate the naive approach.

And for that I've written the following code:

```
simCox[n_] := Module[{}, ct = 1;
  res = 0;
  While[ct <= 10000, 
   data = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[5, 1], n];
   y = Log[data];
   my = Mean[y];
   s2y = Variance[y];
   mx = Mean[data];
   s2x = Variance[data];
   qt = Quantile[StudentTDistribution[n], 0.975];
   If[E^(my + 0.5*s2x - qt*Sqrt[s2y/n + s2y^2/(2 (n - 1))]) < 
     E^(5 + 0.5) < 
     E^(my + 0.5*s2x + qt*Sqrt[s2y/n + s2y^2/(2 (n - 1))]), res++];
   ct++;];
  res = res/10000.]
```

However, when I run

```
Table[simCox[t], {t, 100, 1000, 100}]
```

I get a list full of zeros, which is very different from what I would expect reading the article.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: In the If, I should have written 0.5*s2y instead of 0.5*s2x

Comment: But didn't changing things to 0.5*s2y fix everything?  You now get numbers close to 0.95.  If fixed, why is this question not updated or deleted?

Comment: "when we only observe $\log(y)$" ???  That tells us we can also observe $y$ and $\bar{y}$ is a legitimate (and unbiased) estimate of $E(y)$ for a log normal distribution.

Comment: @JimB I tried to write an answer explaining that, but «To repeat, this information belongs in your original post, not in a reply. Use the Edit button under your post to add it there, and then remove the reply. – Daniel Lichtblau May 9 at 14:14»

Comment: @JimB It's a quote from a comment to a reply I was making to explain how to solve this...

Comment: But the main thing is that your edit fixes the problem.  (That's a good thing.)  So shouldn't the question be closed? Or is there something else that's still wrong?

Comment: @JimB The edit fixes the problem.

Comment: I'd like to say it hasn't happened to me but I certainly can't say that.  I've voted to close the question.